# Jquery ajax call throwing syntax Invalid label error

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to make an ajax call to the server returning a json object, buts its not working... can't figure out whats wrong please help... Here's the code:

```
$.ajax ({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://api.zero1.org/v1/artists",
        data : "",
        dataType : "jsonp"
    }).done (function(msg){
        var artistNames = msg.artists[0].name;

        for (var i = 0; i < artistNames.length; i++) {
            console.log(artistNames[i])
            $('div#artists').html(function() {
                return '<li><a href="details.html"><h3 class="ul-li-heading">' + artistName[i] + '</h3><p class="ul-li-desc">artist/location</p></a></li>'
            });
        } 
    })
```

The JSON object is like so:

```
{
    artists: [
              {
                artistid: "5",
                name: "Outdoor Urban Scene  ",
                bio: "", 
                programs: [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4 
                           ]
              },
              {
                artistid: "87",
                name: "Radames  Ajna",
                bio: "Technical development of Mobile Crash v2",
                programs: [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4
                          ]
              }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource you are attempting to use doesn't support JSONP. The server must be configured properly to process a JSONP request.

You can write some server side code of your own to process the JSON and serve it up, or you can use a service like HQL from Yahoo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
    data: {
        q: 'select * from json where url="http://api.zero1.org/v1/artists"',
        format: 'json'
    },
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `crossDomain` option to your ajax call.Your code must end with `;`

```
$.ajax ({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://api.zero1.org/v1/artists",
        data : "",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true
    }).done (function(msg){
        var artistNames = msg.artists[0].name;

        for (var i = 0; i < artistNames.length; i++) {
            console.log(artistNames[i])
            $('div#artists').html(function() {
                return '<li><a href="details.html"><h3 class="ul-li-heading">' + artistName[i] + '</h3><p class="ul-li-desc">artist/location</p></a></li>'
            });
        } 
    });
```